# How to interpret variable sum restrictions for DEA dual LP models?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems, operations-research

I am studying DEA models and in my textbook there are conflicting definitions on what the sum of the variables in dual model should be.

I am struggling with interpreting the variables as well - I know each variable in the dual model represents a restriction in the primary model and their values are the shadow prices in primary model solution.

- **CRS**

  In CRS the sum of the dual variables does not matter. $e^T\lambda - free$. The graphical representation of the effectivity threshold in CRS should look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTLds.png)
- **VRS**

  In VRS the sum of dual variables should be 1. $e^T\lambda=1$
  The graph for VRS should look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j64RS.png)
- **NIRS**

  Here is where the conflicting information start. In one place the sum of lambda is given as $e^T \lambda \leq 1$, in another as $e^T \lambda > 1$. The graph in NIRS should look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n7oT.png) - I am not 100 % sure on my graph here, I sourced it from [here](https://www.cgdev.org/sites/default/files/archive/doc/stata/MO/DEA/dea_in_stata.pdf), page 3
- **NDRS**

  Again, same conflicting information about the dual variable restriction: $\lambda \geq 1$ and $e^T \lambda < 1$. Graph for NDRS [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmrAP.png). Again, if it's incorrect please let me know how to correct it - [source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378779620304788), fig 1.

**What I would like to know:**

- How to interpret $\lambda$ in the dual model
- Which version for the $\lambda$ restrictions for NIRS and NDRS are correct? And how to logically interpret the restriction?